# What address is this pointer assignment returning?

Tags: c, pointers

I was playing around with pointers the other day and came up with the following code where I explicitly cast an `int` variable to `int *` and print out the address of the explicitly casted variable

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int d;
    int *p1, *p2;

    printf("%p\n", p1 = &d);
    printf("%p\n", p2 = (int *) d);

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
ffbff71c
ffbff878
```

My question is what is that second address and what is contained there?

Comment: My question is, as in all of these situations, why you felt the need to do this

Comment: I wanted to see what would happen so I experimented. When I saw what happened, I wasn't sure what to make of it, so I asked a question.

Answer (score 5):

Garbage - you're printing out the value of an uninitialized variable. It's just total coincidence that it looks like your other address; initialize `d` to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: @sunqingyao - I just mean it will become obvious what value is printed out since it will match the initialization of `d`.

Answer (score 2):

In the second print, you are not printing an address, but a value converted to an address!

In the first assignment, you're taking the address of the variable, which is just some RAM address. In the second assignment, you're converting the variable's value to a pointer. Since the variable is not initialized, that's the garbage value located at that RAM address.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a random address in memory since d is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you are converting an indeterminate value to a pointer.  Performing that conversion, or indeed doing *anything* with that value other than overwriting it, produces undefined behavior.

If `d`'s value were set prior to the conversion, then it would matter that C explicitly permits integers to be converted to pointers.  However, for this case and most others, the standard says:

> the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.

[C2011, 6.3.2.3/5]

So basically, don't do that unless you know enough to determine reliably for yourself what the result will be with your particular combination of code, C implementation, compile and link options, and platform.